# Can you include relational data in an index on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, indexing

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

I have two tables like this:

**OrderItems**

```
OrderItemID
InventoryItemID
```

and :

**InventoryItems**

```
InventoryItemID
ItemCode
```

My query plan shows a lot of time getting sucked into joining the `InventoryItemID`s to get the `ItemCode` for every order item.

I already have a nonclustered index that includes both columns on both tables, but would like to make it even faster -- can I "import" the relational `ItemCode` into the `OrderItems` table's index?

Comment: Look at your execution plan, is it using the idex on the foreign key? If it is part of a compound index and it is not the first field, it might not be using the existing index and a separate index just for the FK may need to be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot INCLUDE columns from another table. However, one, 'outside the box' suggestion would be to create an Indexed View that joins OrderItems and InventoryItems. You can setup your clustered index on the view in such a way to achieve fastest performance and it would appear that both orders and inventory items are in the same "table", without the need to do a join. The result would be a somewhat denormalized view of the data.

Of course, there are a number of restrictions on an Indexed View, but an inner join is permitted. I have used Index Views quite frequently and they can be tremendously useful. There is a insert / update / delete performance consideration here, because each of the operations will require an update to the view. But, it might be worth it.